# SQL WHERE clause match two (or more) joined rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume these tables:

```
customer with age column
order with customer_id and item_id column
```

I need a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM customer c 
   JOIN order o ON c.id = o.customer_id
   WHERE c.age > 30 
   AND (c has ordered item_id 1 AND item_id 2)
```

There is one row for each ordered item in the order table

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

It will return the customer who ordered the `item_id 1 and 2`

```
SELECT c.id 
FROM customer c 
JOIN order o ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE c.age > 30 AND o.item_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY c.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.item_id) = 2
```

Sample execution:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (Id VARCHAR (200), Age INT);
INSERT INTO Customer (Id, Age) VALUES (1, 25), (2, 31), (3, 35), (4, 40);

CREATE TABLE Order (customer_id VARCHAR (200), item_id INT);
INSERT INTO Order(customer_id, item_id) VALUES
(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3);

SELECT c.Id 
FROM customer c 
JOIN order o ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE c.age > 30 AND o.item_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY c.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.item_id) = 2
```

Result:

```
Id
----
2
4
```

Comment: @dve Is the answer helps you?

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient method might be:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where c.age > 30 and
      exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.customer_id and o.item_id = 1) and
      exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.customer_id and o.item_id = 2) ;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `customer(age, id)` and `orders(customer_id, item_id)`.  Do note that storing age in a table is usually not reasonable because age changes all the time.